# Two content Providers

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider

I am developing an application and the app has a database with two table so my question is should both table have their own helper class and should each has it own content provider and if their are two versions of both wont the helper of first table conflict with the helper of second and if it is one it will be very difficult maintaining content uri ?

What will be the best way to implement this structure.

Comment: Do as you like. All is possible.